# New to Python programming, could somebody please explain the fault with this program?

Tags: python

I am very new to Python programming, I am writing a simple fighting game at the moment (text based) that is extremely simple as I'm just learning the basics at the moment.
I have placed the code for my game below (it is not finished), my problem is that every time I run the program, when you enter which character you'd like to play as this error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\combat.py", line 60, in <module>
    first_player.attack(second_player)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is the code for my game (don't worry it's not very big!).

```
import time
import random

class player(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.account = name
        self.health = random.randint(50,100)
        self.attack = random.randint(30,40)
        self.alive = True

    def __str__(self):

        if self.alive:
            return "%s (%i health, %i attack)" % (self.account, self.health, self.attack)
        else:
            return self.account, "is dead!"

    def attack(self, enemy):

        print self.account, "attacks", enemy.account, "with %s attack!" % self.attack
        enemy.health -= self.attack
        if enemy.health <= 0:
            enemy.die()

    def die(self):
            print self.account, "dies!"

alive_players = 2

name1 = raw_input("Enter a name: ")
name2 = raw_input("Enter another name: ")

player_list = {"a":player(name1), "b":player(name2)}

while alive_players == 2:

    print
    for player_name in sorted(player_list.keys()):
        print player_name, player_list[player_name]
    print

    player1 = raw_input("Who would you like to play as? (a/b): ").lower()

    try:
        first_player=player_list[player1]
    except KeyError, wrong_name:
        print wrong_name, "does not exist!"
        continue

    if first_player==player(name1):
        second_player=player(name2)
    else:
        second_player=player(name1)

    time.sleep(1)
    print
    print "*" * 30
    first_player.attack(second_player)
    second_player.attack(first_player)
```

I know There are workarounds like appending the characters to the list AFTER the player picks the names, although I would like to have a further understanding of classes and want to know why this does not work! If possible could somebody please explain the fault and how I can fix it? I have been looking at this for three days, I could do it differently and make it work, but I would like to understand why THIS doesn't work first!

Thanks in advance!
-Charlie

Comment: Isn't that a question for codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 9):

`first_player.attack` is a number because of `self.attack = random.randint(30,40)`. I suspect that you want that named differently so that it doesn't overwrite your `attack` method.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd give you all positive reputation for these answers if I could, although I require 15 reputation first, you are rewarded with the delight that you just helped somebody getting started!

(Sorry for copying this comment to the other two answers, all three answers were a great help!)

Answer (score 8):

`__init__()` shadows the `attack()` method on the object. Use a different name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd give you all positive reputation for these answers if I could, although I require 15 reputation first, you are rewarded with the delight that you just helped somebody getting started!

(Sorry for copying this comment to the other two answers, all three answers were a great help!)

Answer (score 2):

The variable for each players attack-strength has the same name as the function for attack, so when you call first_player.attack(), it's trying to call an int as if it was a function. Rename the function to something like "attack_player()" or the attack rating as "attack_value", or something, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd give you all positive reputation for these answers if I could, although I require 15 reputation first, you are rewarded with the delight that you just helped somebody getting started!

(Sorry for copying this comment to the other two answers, all three answers were a great help!)